# Azure blob file download failed after downloading a few files

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I tried to download blob files using BlobClient.downloadToFile(dest), but it failed after downloading a few files. I faced the same issue while trying to download a 3GB single file from Azure Blob storage.

```
package com.blob.download;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.ListBlobsOptions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class BlobDownload {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        BlobServiceClientBuilder builder = new BlobServiceClientBuilder();
        //Specify storage uri
        String storageBaseUri = "";
        ///Specify connection string
        String connectionString = "";
        //Specify blob list prefix
        String key = "";
        builder.connectionString(connectionString);
        BlobServiceClient client = builder.buildClient();
        if (!storageBaseUri.startsWith(client.getAccountUrl())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The given credential can not be used for the specified container.");
        }
        String containerName = storageBaseUri.replace(client.getAccountUrl() + "/", "");
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = client.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        System.out.println("Downloading " + blobContainerClient.getBlobContainerName() + "/" + key);
        Iterator<BlobItem> keyspaceBlobs =
                blobContainerClient.listBlobs(new ListBlobsOptions().setPrefix(key + "/"), null).iterator();
        while (keyspaceBlobs.hasNext()){
            BlobItem blob = keyspaceBlobs.next();
            Path destFile = Paths.get("/opt/data/", blob.getName());
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(destFile.getParent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            blobContainerClient
                    .getBlobClient(blob.getName())
                    .downloadToFile(destFile.toString());
            System.out.println("Download file succeeded : " + destFile.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
nettyTcNativeVersion = '2.0.7.Final'
compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.4.0'
compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.0.6'
```

I have got the following error message

```
Exception in thread "main" reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:393)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1678)
    at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.blockWithOptionalTimeout(StorageImplUtils.java:99)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.downloadToFileWithResponse(BlobClientBase.java:563)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.downloadToFile(BlobClientBase.java:488)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.downloadToFile(BlobClientBase.java:457)
    at com.blob.download.BlobDownload.main(BlobDownload.java:57)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:247)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1147)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can you please guide me if there is any wrong usage in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I have do a test. Your code is basically no problem.

> but it failed after downloading a few files.

How many files do you download? I use your code and it seems work fine.

> I faced the same issue while trying to download a 3GB single file from
> Azure Blob storage.

Based on your code, 3gb will cause problem. You need to download the file by blocks to prevent the handshake timeout problem.

Comment: > How many files do you download?


Following are the test results

* Azure blob file download working fine with 1200 files (Total file size is 52.32 MiB)
* Azure blob file download failed with  single 3GB file (java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer)
* Azure blob file download failed after downloading 251 files  (167 Mb is the max size of single file ,  Total downloaded file size is  3.6G)
* Azure blob file download failed after downloading 5 files (Each file size is 167 Mb)